# Which is a better interface for designing an ASP.net application: drag and drop or manual positioning?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

Which is a better interface for designing an ASP.net application: drag and drop or manual positioning?

Comment: I vote manual positioning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That defines on how you define "better".

---

"Better" in the sense that even an unskilled developer can get a webform up and running in no time: **Use drag and drop**.

---

"Better" in the sense that it gives a skilled developer more control over the generated HTML and CSS, potentially leading to

- more robust layouting, compatible with a wide range of browsers, and
- easier maintainance, due to a lack of unnecessary tags and attributes:

**Use manual positioning** and a lot of knowledge about HTML and CSS.

Comment: Thanks for giving this advice sir! I will use manual positioning now :)

Comment: @RoronoaZoro: You're welcome! Note that you can use both at the same time; try the "split view" of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

**You use them all** - anything to make the design you look for.

Drag Drop, Manual position, tweak changes, css write/change/delete/re-write, copy/paste, open close ten programs, search on google for other css, anything to make what you have on paper - and then is not good and you start over. Anything you can have you use it.